# Increasing the Heap Size in JVM

Tags: jboss, jvm

What should be done if one has to force jboss to run on 64 bits?

- windows is 64 bit
- jboss is also 64 bit
- java version "1.6.0_25"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

But I need to have the jvm heap increased to 4 GB

For that JVM should be running on 64 bits else one can't increase the size beyond 2 GB

Comment: just a note, you shouldn't be running java 1.6 in 2015 if you can avoid it.

Comment: ... even Java 7 should be avoided as it is end of free support soon.  The last version will be released in May 2015. If you must use a really old version of Java, you should use Java 6 update 45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open for edit file bin/standalone.conf, find JAVA_OPTS parameter and change -Xmx subvalue of them.

Example:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx4g".
```